# jQuery code doesn't work correctly in Chrome & IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser

I have the following javascript code in a HTML document which loads Html in a div:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#submenu a").click(function(){
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);
        $.get(page+".html",function(gotHtml){
            $("#contenedorprincipal").html(gotHtml);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

In Firefox it runs perfectly, but in Chrome and IE it does not work. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Do you get an error? I suspect the `hash` property is not implemented in Chrome/IE...

Comment: *what* doesn't work ? What results do you expect ? What results do you have ? Can you paste the related HTML code ?

Comment: It would be better if you could write a more descriptive title, and give a bit more information including the html and a description about what is actually going wrong. It can often help to create a live example to go along with your question using something like http://jsfiddle.net or provide a url to your site.
@gdoron: You could have been a little more helpful to the first time poster instead of being sarcastic.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should give you more info about the problem. Is my first time, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to me like it works in chrome... any way try this: http://jsfiddle.net/8daxU/

replace the wrapping function with (I added an alert just to show the hash - remove at afterwords)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submenu a").click(function(){
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);
        alert(page);
        $("#contenedorprincipal").load(page+".html");
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Yaron for the Answer but Chrome seems not like something.. :(

The alert works correctly but the html don't appear in div..

Comment: are you sure that you have the specific page in the same folder? take a look at the "network" tab in the developers tools of chrome to see if you can find the request and let us know what the response is

Comment: I've found the request URL in Chrome and... it's ok! I don't understand the reason why Chrome don't "paint" the html...

Comment: can you post some online link that we'll be able to investigate it ourselves?

Comment: I've found this in network tab of chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load, Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin...

Comment: is it possible that youre trying to run this script through the file system and not through a web server? if so - this is probably the problem

Comment: Exactly.. that's the problem! thanks Yaron for your help! I'm trying run the script through file system.. however I don't understand why..

Comment: what don't you understand? the file system is not a real web server - therefore it doesn't have a domain / IP etc... when you're trying to call an AJAX (even when the file is in the same folder) - it tries to load it through a web server - and then it gets a cross-domain-policy error

Answer (score 0):

This should work across browsers:

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $( '#contenedorprincipal' );

    $( '#submenu' ).on( 'click', 'a', function ( e ) {
        $content.load( this.href.split( '#' )[1] + '.html' );
    });
});
```